# CSS Responsive Image positioning and cropping

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a **foreground** image (not background) that covers the entire viewport.  When the page is resized or viewed on a smaller device I want the most important part of the image to be centered with any part that doesn't fit in the window cropped on its width (not its height).  To clarify lets assume that this represents the horizontal pixels in a 10 bit pixel wide image that I want to center on pixel #7.

|0123456789|

displayed on a wider screen might be:
|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9|      (still encompassing the entire screen)

resized for a smaller screen:
|123456789|
  |23456789|   <-- Even smaller screen
     |3456789|   <-- Even smaller screen
        |456789|   <-- Even smaller screen
        |45678|     <-- Even smaller screen
           |5678|     <-- Even smaller screen
              |678|     <-- Even smaller screen
              |67|        <-- Even smaller screen
                 |7|        <-- Even smaller screen

In this example the entire picture shows when the screen is large enough to display the entire picture.  But when the screen shrinks, it should properly crop (mostly from the left) in order to make sure that #7 is always displayed with proportional movement towards the center of the screen.  How can I do this?  CSS, javascript and JQuery must be able to handle this.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b7o7n7gd/

Comment: background-size + background-position will do, it is their jobs :) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jqjdrp

Comment: @GCyrillus Thank you!  It looks beautiful.  That was a lot quicker answer than I was expecting!

Comment: @jmargolisvt -Not exactly what I was looking for but informational as I hadn't worked with Bootstrap in the past (new web developer).  Thank you for enlightening me on an obvious requirement for future development.

Comment: @gibberish - Thank you. It looks great!

Answer (score 1):

**edit**, since it is foreground :
the idea here is to use `line-height, text-align , min-height, min-width` and negative `margin` to crop the image: average result below in snippet or [codepen](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ONedzQ/)

```css
html {
  height:100%;
}
body {
  text-align:right;
  line-height:100vh;
  height:100%;
}

img {
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  margin:-50% 0 -50% -240%  ;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x200&text=123456789" />
```

from my comment:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: url(http://dummyimage.com/600x200&text=123456789) 73% center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

the idea is, once page resized, the last number to be seen is 7.

You need to run the snippet in fullpage or play with the codepen liked earlier : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jqjdrp

Answer (score 0):

Think you're just looking for background-position: center?

```css
/*.with-bg-size*/ html {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1600x1600');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="with-bg-size"></div>
```

Comment: If I am right you example won't crop and it will only keep the dead center of the picture in the center of the screen.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, it crops. Here, try using this background-image instead :):
    background-image: url('http://purrfectcatbreeds.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/large-cat-breeds-1024x795.jpg');

Comment: you may also be interested in background-size: cover
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

keep aspect ratio of image for responsive

```
div:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: (16 / 9) * 100%;
  }
```